# Javascript number.toLocaleString currency without currency sign

Tags: javascript, localization, formatting, currency

Suppose we have

```
var number = 123456.789;
```

What I want is to display this number in locale 'de-DE' as

```
123.456,79
```

in locale 'ja-JP' as

```
123,457
```

in locale 'en-US' as

```
123,456.79
```

and so on according to user's locale. The problem is that Javascript's `number.toLocaleString` requires to specify currency sign and I can't find out how to tell to not display it at all.

What I tried:

```
number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency' }));
// TypeError: undefined currency in NumberFormat() with currency style

number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: '' }));
// RangeError: invalid currency code in NumberFormat():

number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: false }));
// RangeError: invalid currency code in NumberFormat(): false

number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: null }));
// RangeError: invalid currency code in NumberFormat(): null
```

The function also has option `currencyDisplay`. I tried the same values as above with `currency` option but with same result.

---

**UPDATE** (2020-11-25)

A few people pointed to `.resolvedOptions()`. It basically solves the question:

```
const currencyFractionDigits = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
}).resolvedOptions().maximumFractionDigits;

const value = (12345.678).toLocaleString('de-DE', {
    maximumFractionDigits: currencyFractionDigits 
});

console.log(value); // prints 12.345,68
```

Thank you.

Comment: The following statement is wrong: "The problem is that Javascript's number.toLocaleString requires to specify currency sign". You can simply pass the locale string as in `number.toLocaleString('de-DE')`

Comment: If you want $0.50 to be formatted 0.50 and not 0.5, 
{ minimumFractionDigits: currencyFractionDigits} worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

There is no way to pass parameter to `toLocaleString` and remove currency symbol. so use this function instead.

`var convertedNumber = num.toLocaleString('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });`

Comment: And how do I know the number of locale's currency fraction digits? It might be 0, 2 or 3.

Comment: copy my line in a function and pass that fraction digit in a variable as argument . I'm using the same way. that is what `minimumFractionDigits` is for.

Comment: I know where to pass fraction digit. What I don't know is how to get that digit in javascript.

Comment: didn't mean to offend you or question your programming skills. I might havn't  understood your question properly brother.

Comment: `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).resolvedOptions()` will return an object describing how to format the number including `minimumIntegerDigits`, `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` fields

Comment: How to get other formatting options - fractional and thousand separators? A complete code would be useful.

Answer (score 18):

Here how I solved this issue. When I want to format currency without any signs, I format it with the currency code and then just remove 3-chars code from the result.

```
export function getCurrencyFormatWithSymbol(currencyCode) {
  return {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
  }
}

export function getCurrencyFormatWithIsoCode(currencyCode) {
  return {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    currencyDisplay: 'code',
  }
}

export function getCurrencyFormatWithLocalName(currencyCode) {
  return {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    currencyDisplay: 'name',
  }
}

export function getCurrencyFormatNumbersOnly(currencyCode) {
  return {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currencyCode,
    currencyDisplay: 'none',
  }
}

export function formatCurrency (value, format, lang) {
  const stripSymbols = (format.currencyDisplay === 'none')
  const localFormat = stripSymbols ? {...format, currencyDisplay: 'code'} : format
  let result = Intl.NumberFormat(lang, localFormat).format(value)
  if (stripSymbols) {
    result = result.replace(/[a-z]{3}/i, "").trim()
  }
  return result
}
```

Usage:

```
const format = getCurrencyFormatNumbersOnly('JPY')
formatCurrency(12345, format, 'ja')
formatCurrency(123456, format, 'ja')
formatCurrency(1234567, format, 'ja')
formatCurrency(12345678, format, 'ja')
```

Edit: The only minus, in this case, is the speed. On simple tasks, it will work perfectly. But if you are going to format a lot of numbers (for example, if you are fetching financial reports with raw data from backend and then format numbers according to user settings) this function can slow down your algorithms significantly and become a bottleneck on some browsers. So, test it carefully before using in production.

Comment: It is useful but I still hope that there is an option in number.toLocaleString that we don't know about.

Comment: It seems your question can not be solved by native JS tools. I was searching for the same issue and didn't found anything. So the only way it was possible in my project was that I've shown above.

Comment: currencyDisplay: "none" is not valid https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Comment: @Ray If you look at the code more carefully, you'll see that the `none` value is only used in my own code and not passed to the `Intl.NumberFormat()` method. Instead, it is replaced by the `code` value if `none` is used in the configuration. The `none` value is only used to configure my custom functions.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution that isn't using regex and will deal with any locale, properly.

It uses the currency formatter of the locale and iterates all parts of it to exclude the literal and currency, properly, resulting in only getting the number as string. (Btw, the literal is the space between number and currency symbol).

```js
const value = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR',
}).formatToParts(12345.678).map(
    p => p.type != 'literal' && p.type != 'currency' ? p.value : ''
).join('')

console.log(value) // prints 12.345,68
```

Comment: This looks clever at the first glance, but unfortunately doesn’t work. It does not consider all currency-locale- combination specific options.

In case of `fr-CH` with `CHF`, it will use a decimal comma instead of a decimal point.
https://jsfiddle.net/e80vutwq/

Comment: @KohlerDominik You are right, I updated my answer to fix this. The issue was `toLocaleString` with `style: 'decimal'` will use the number decimal sign of the given language, not the currency decimal sign. It's not possible to set the decimal sign when calling `toLocaleString`, however I found a simpler solution. Simply use the currency formatter and extract all parts using `formatToParts`, excluding the currency symbol. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, now it will work. It's now literally a duplicate of the one from @nyg below.

Comment: @KohlerDominik Oh, I didn't see his answer and worked this out by myself. I can see that his solution will not exclude the literal and trim the value instead, but this will only work for currencies that use a whitespace as literal. Also I'm joining the segments whereas he uses `reduce` for that. I didn't intend to come that close to an already-existing solution, but mine should be slightly faster and more fail-proof whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

The solution proposed in the OP won't work for the `fr-CH` locale because there is a distinction between a “currency amount” and a “non-currency amount”. The former uses a dot as decimal separator whereas the latter uses a comma:

```js
const n = 1234.56
console.log(n.toLocaleString('fr-CH'))
console.log(n.toLocaleString('fr-CH', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'CHF'
}))
```

Using `.replace()` either with a regex or directly with the currency code does seem to be the fastest solution but here is a solution with the [`.formatToParts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) function of NumberFormat and how it can be used to solve the OP's question:

```js
console.log(new Intl
  .NumberFormat('fr-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' })
  .formatToParts(1234.56) // returns an array of the different parts of the amount
  .filter(p => p.type != 'currency') // removes the currency part
  .reduce((s, p) => s + p.value, '') // joins the remaining values
  .trim())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `currencyDisplay: 'code'` option, and since you know the currency code you can easily replace it by the symbol you want :

```
return Intl.NumberFormat(language, {
    style: 'currency', currency: currency.code, currencyDisplay: 'code'
  }).format(amount).replace(currency.code, currency.symbol);
```

This way you're keeping all the currency formatting standards implied in `NumberFormat` and replacing only the symbol. In your case the custom symbol would be an empty string (`''`) and you may want to trim your string too with `.trim()`.

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation on the OPs answer including the minimumFractionDigits

```js
const resolvedOptions = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP', }).resolvedOptions();
const currencyOptions = {
    minimumFractionDigits: resolvedOptions.minimumFractionDigits,
    maximumFractionDigits: resolvedOptions.maximumFractionDigits
}
const value = (12345.678).toLocaleString('en-GB', currencyOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread by searching this use case, and the trick i use using class **Intl.NumberFormat**, with Regex of symbol it supported on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.The trick is take currency symbol and using it as a needle for regex replace after localisation.

This sample code should do the trick:

```
var number = 123456.789;

function getCurrencySymbol(locale, currency) {
  return (0).toLocaleString(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }).replace(/\d/g, '').trim();
}
var numeric_format = new Intl.NumberFormat('id-ID', { style: 'currency', currency: 'IDR', currencyDisplay: 'symbol' });
var localCurrencySymbol  = getCurrencySymbol('id-ID', 'IDR');
var CurrencySymbolNeedle = new RegExp(localCurrencySymbol, "g");

var amount = numeric_format.format(number);
console.log(localCurrencySymbol); // Rp
console.log(amount); // Rp 123.456,79
amount = amount.replace(CurrencySymbolNeedle, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');
console.log(amount); // 123.456,79
```

I don't test if this class support cross browser

Edit: 
Function to get currency symbol take from [Get the currency symbol for a locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650503/get-the-currency-symbol-for-a-locale)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to **split the string with the sign**, and then get the second value of the array.

```js
// value 350011
 const valueFormated = (value).toLocaleString('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
 });

 valueFormated.split('$')
 // if you console.log the result would be
 (2) ['', '3,500.11']

 // here is the value formated
 valueFormated.split('$')[1]
 // 3,500.11
```

Comment: Splitting is not a good option because sometimes the sign comes last in some currencies, and you can't guess.

Comment: @AdamAAllalou from my testing the position of the currencyDisplay is set by locale. If you do 'en' it will always be at the start, 'de' at the end. So you should have a reliable position if you set the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the currency sign? If not `number.toLocaleString('de-DE')` should do the trick.

Comment: And how do I know the number of locale's currency fraction digits? It might be 0, 2 or 3: https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

Comment: Sorry, i think i might have misunderstood you. What is your use-case?

Comment: @dMedia. `new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR', }).resolvedOptions().maximumFractionDigits`

Answer (score 0):

```
const locale = 'en-US';
const currency = 'USD';

const getCurrencySymbol = () =>
  (0)
    .toLocaleString(locale, {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: currency,
      maximumFractionDigits: 0,
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    })
    .replace(/\d/g, '')
    .trim();

const formattedNumberWithoutSymbol = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: currency,
}).format(499.99).replace(getCurrencySymbol(), '');

console.log(formattedNumberWithoutSymbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla's documentation, there is the `style` option `"decimal"` which returns the plain number:

> "decimal" (default)
> For plain number formatting.

Code looks like this (`style` is optional in this case):

```js
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'decimal', currency: 'EUR', maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(
    number,
  ),
);
// Expected output: "123.456,79"
```

Try it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat

Answer (score -1):

Just put options as:

> { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }

```
const s = 1234.567 
const options = { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }
const result = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', options).format(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

according to MDN you can use following format

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number))
```

use **maximumSignificantDigits** option only

Comment: And how do we get the maximumSignificantDigits value?

Comment: @dMedia it's a value you use based on need. in some cases you need two digit separation, in cases you need 3 digit separation. mostly depends on the currency system

Comment: The question was basically about how to get the number of the locale's currency fraction digits.

Answer (score -1):

Since you know the currency symbol being formated you can just use
`.substring(n)` accordingly based on the currency symbol and its position.

Answer (score -2):

**THIS WHAT YOU NEED TO DO**

`new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(6700); //return 6,700.00 without currency,`

Comment: then you don't get the right decimals, always. eg try BHD