# Not getting all symbols for currencies using .toLocaleString

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the symbol for a list of currencies stored in an XML file.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OTACurrencies xmlns="http://www.cartrawler.com/">
<OTACurrency Code="FJD">Fijian dollar</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MXN">MXN</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BBD">BBD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="GTQ">GTQ</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CLP">CLP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="HNL">HNL</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="UGX">UGX</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ZAR">South Africa Rand</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="TND">TND</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BSD">BSD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="SDG">SDG</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CUP">CUP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="TWD">TWD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="RSD">RSD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="DOP">DOP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MYR">MYR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XOF">XOF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="UYU">UYU</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MAD">MAD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CVE">CVE</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="OMR">OMR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="SEK">Sweden Kronor</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="KES">KES</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="UAH">UAH</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="GNF">GNF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ERN">ERN</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MZN">MZN</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ARS">ARS</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="QAR">QAR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="IRR">IRR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MRO">MRO</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XPD">XPD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CNY">CNY</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="THB">THB</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XPF">XPF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="UZS">UZS</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BDT">BDT</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="LYD">LYD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BMD">BMD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="PHP">PHP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="KWD">KWD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XPT">XPT</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="RUB">RUB</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ISK">ISK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="JMD">JMD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="COP">COP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="USD">US Dollarw</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MKD">MKD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="DZD">DZD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="SGD">SGD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="VEB">VEB</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ETB">ETB</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="VEF">VEF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="VUV">VUV</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ZMK">ZMK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BND">BND</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XAF">XAF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XAG">XAG</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CHF">Swiss Francs</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="HRK">HRK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ALL">ALL</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="TZS">TZS</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="VND">VND</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XAU">XAU</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="AUD">Australian Dollars</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ILS">ILS</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="GHS">GHS</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BOB">BOB</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="IDR">IDR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="AMD">AMD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BWP">BWP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="TRY">TRY</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="LBP">LBP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="JOD">JOD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="AED">AED</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="HKD">HKD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="RWF">RWF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="EUR">Eurow</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="LSL">LSL</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="DKK">Denmark Kroner</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ZWD">ZWD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CAD">Canadian Dollars</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BGN">BGN</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="EEK">EEK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MMK">MMK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MUR">MUR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="NOK">Norwegian Kroner</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="SYP">SYP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="RON">RON</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="LKR">LKR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="NGN">NGN</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CZK">CZK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="CRC">CRC</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="PKR">PKR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XCD">XCD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="ANG">ANG</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BHD">BHD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="SZL">SZL</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="KZT">KZT</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="SAR">SAR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="LTL">LTL</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="TTD">TTD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="YER">YER</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="INR">INR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="KRW">KRW</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="JPY">JPY</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MNT">MNT</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="PLN">Polish Złoty</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="AOA">AOA</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="GBP">GB Pound</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="HUF">HUF</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MWK">MWK</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MGA">MGA</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="XDR">XDR</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BAM">BAM</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="EGP">EGP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="MOP">MOP</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="NAD">NAD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="PEN">PEN</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="NZD">NZD</OTACurrency>
<OTACurrency Code="BRL">BRL</OTACurrency>
</OTACurrencies>
```

This is the code that is responsible to get the symbol:

```
function getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode) {
    return (0)
        .toLocaleString('en', {style: 'currency', currency: currencyCode})
        .replace(/[0,.]/g, '')
        .trim();
}

function setSelectedCurrency(currencyCode, shouldInsertQuery) {
    if (typeof shouldInsertQuery !== 'boolean') {
        shouldInsertQuery = true;
    }

    selectedCurrency = currencyCode;
    var symbol = getCurrencySymbol(currencyCode);
    $('#currency-selector').text(currencyCode + ' ' + symbol);
    window.localStorage.setItem('bonocar-last_selected-currency', currencyCode);
    if (shouldInsertQuery) {
        insertParam('curr', currencyCode);
    }
}

function filterCurrencies() {
    var inputValue = $('#currency-selector-filter').val().trim();
    if (inputValue === '') {
        showAvailableCurrencies(currencies);
    } else {
        const fc = currencies.filter(function(c) {
            return c.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        showAvailableCurrencies(fc);
    }
}

function showAvailableCurrencies(availableCurrencies) {
    var currencyItemsDropdown = $('.currency-selector-dropdown-ul');
    var currencyElementItems = document.createDocumentFragment();

    availableCurrencies.forEach(function(c) {
        var content = c + ' ' + getCurrencySymbol(c);
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = content;
        item.onclick = function() {
            setSelectedCurrency(c);
        }
        currencyElementItems.append(item);
    });

    currencyItemsDropdown.html('');
    currencyItemsDropdown.append(currencyElementItems);
}
```

When I look at the DOM, I notice only a few currencies get converted:

```
<ul class="currency-selector-dropdown-ul"><li>FJD FJD</li><li>MXN MX$</li><li>BBD BBD</li><li>GTQ GTQ</li><li>CLP CLP</li><li>HNL HNL</li><li>UGX UGX</li><li>ZAR ZAR</li><li>TND TND</li><li>BSD BSD</li><li>SDG SDG</li><li>CUP CUP</li><li>TWD NT$</li><li>RSD RSD</li><li>DOP DOP</li><li>MYR MYR</li><li>XOF CFA</li><li>UYU UYU</li><li>MAD MAD</li><li>CVE CVE</li><li>OMR OMR</li><li>SEK SEK</li><li>KES KES</li><li>UAH UAH</li><li>GNF GNF</li><li>ERN ERN</li><li>MZN MZN</li><li>ARS ARS</li><li>QAR QAR</li><li>IRR IRR</li><li>MRO MRO</li><li>XPD XPD</li><li>CNY CN¥</li><li>THB THB</li><li>XPF CFPF</li><li>UZS UZS</li><li>BDT BDT</li><li>LYD LYD</li><li>BMD BMD</li><li>PHP PHP</li><li>KWD KWD</li><li>XPT XPT</li><li>RUB RUB</li><li>ISK ISK</li><li>JMD JMD</li><li>COP COP</li><li>USD $</li><li>MKD MKD</li><li>DZD DZD</li><li>SGD SGD</li><li>VEB VEB</li><li>ETB ETB</li><li>VEF VEF</li><li>VUV VUV</li><li>ZMK ZMK</li><li>BND BND</li><li>XAF FCFA</li><li>XAG XAG</li><li>CHF CHF</li><li>HRK HRK</li><li>ALL ALL</li><li>TZS TZS</li><li>VND ₫</li><li>XAU XAU</li><li>AUD A$</li><li>ILS ₪</li><li>GHS GHS</li><li>BOB BOB</li><li>IDR IDR</li><li>AMD AMD</li><li>BWP BWP</li><li>TRY TRY</li><li>LBP LBP</li><li>JOD JOD</li><li>AED AED</li><li>HKD HK$</li><li>RWF RWF</li><li>EUR €</li><li>LSL LSL</li><li>DKK DKK</li><li>ZWD ZWD</li><li>CAD CA$</li><li>BGN BGN</li><li>EEK EEK</li><li>MMK MMK</li><li>MUR MUR</li><li>NOK NOK</li><li>SYP SYP</li><li>RON RON</li><li>LKR LKR</li><li>NGN NGN</li><li>CZK CZK</li><li>CRC CRC</li><li>PKR PKR</li><li>XCD EC$</li><li>ANG ANG</li><li>BHD BHD</li><li>SZL SZL</li><li>KZT KZT</li><li>SAR SAR</li><li>LTL LTL</li><li>TTD TTD</li><li>YER YER</li><li>INR ₹</li><li>KRW ₩</li><li>JPY ¥</li><li>MNT MNT</li><li>PLN PLN</li><li>AOA AOA</li><li>GBP £</li><li>HUF HUF</li><li>MWK MWK</li><li>MGA MGA</li><li>XDR XDR</li><li>BAM BAM</li><li>EGP EGP</li><li>MOP MOP</li><li>NAD NAD</li><li>PEN PEN</li><li>NZD NZ$</li><li>BRL R$</li></ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After some research and trying out different solutions, I have to agree with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53749034 and suggest using a library that has a map of known symbols for each currency.