# Getting only currency symbol based on Intl.NumberFormat or similar

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is an `Intl.NumberFormat` option or something similar, that just returns the currency symbol based on a given input.

```
let formatted = (new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(1)) 
//=> returns 1.00 €
//=>what I would need, just => €
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: May also be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650503/get-the-currency-symbol-for-a-locale